# How to move marker on a map with mapbox api using json and php?

Tags: php, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I'm using mapbox api to display maps and directions. It's easy and it works well. I want to know how to update a marker's location on the map without refreshing a page. I read this [page](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/locate-user/) and [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/live-update-feature/?q=realtime&size=n_10_n) page in their documentation. I understand their examples but I'm not fully grasping how to implement realtime data in my codes without causing the page to refresh. Right now I have a script that updates the user location in the database every 15 seconds and returns longitude, latitude. I have the data now what? This is where I get highly confused. If you can help I would really appreciate. I have stripped down the codes for the sake of this question.

**map.html**

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.7.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.7.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="geolocation.js"></script>

    <!--Display map-->
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!--mapbox script-->
    <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken ='pk.xxxxxxxx';
                var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
                container: 'map',
                style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
                center:[$longitude,$latitude],
                zoom: 15
                });
                var geojson = {
                    type: 'FeatureCollection',

                    features: [{
                        type: 'Feature',
                        geometry: {
                        type: 'Point',
                        coordinates:[$longitude,$latitude]
                        },
                        properties: {
                        title: '',
                        description: ''
                        }}]
                    };

                    geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {
                    var el = document.createElement('div');
                    el.className = 'marker';
                    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
                    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
                    .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) 
                    .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>'))
                    .addTo(map);
                    });
     </script>
```

**geolocation.js**

```
setInterval(function () {
$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function (response) {

    //variables
    var user_id = $('.userid').val();
    var geoLocation = response.loc;

    //build array
    var values ='geoLocation=' + encodeURIComponent(geoLocation)
    + '&userid=' + encodeURIComponent(user_id);

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://mywebsite.com/mobile/geolocation.php',
    data: values,
    success: function (data) {


    //returns new longitude
    var lon = data.longitude;

    //returns new latitude
    var lat = data.latitude;

    }
    });
}, "jsonp");
}, 15000);
```

**geolocation.php**

```
$geoLocation= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['geoLocation']);//coordinates
$userid= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['userid']);//userid

//split coordinates into lat and longitude
$longitude = substr($geoLocation, strpos($geoLocation, ",") + 1); //put it first
$latitude =preg_replace('/^([^,]*).*$/', '$1', $geoLocation);  // put it second

//insert new coordinates
$insertgeo = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_geolocation (latitude,longitude,userid)  VALUES(?,?,?)");
$insertgeo->bind_param("sss",$latitude,$longitude,$userid);
$insertgeo->execute();
$insertgeo->close();

//return answer to json
$result = array('message' => 'success',
                'userid'=>$userid,
                'longitude'=>$longitude,
                'latitude'=>$latitude);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation resources you've linked are helpful, but I think this [add live realtime data](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/live-geojson/) example is even better for your use case. If you zoom out of the map to see a larger region of the world, you will see a blue rocket icon marker which moves every two seconds without refreshing the page. In essence, this is exactly what you're looking to do! I'll explain how the example is working so that you can use the same logic to update your own marker locations without refreshing the page as well.

The rocket icon in this example is added to the map with a source and layer. The [source](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/) specifies all the underlying data (in this case, the updating GeoJSON served by the [https://wanderdrone.appspot.com](https://wanderdrone.appspot.com/) URL), and the [layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/) specifies how that data should be styled on the map. If you visit this URL, you'll see that the `coordinates` update each time you refresh the page.

So, the code below:

1. Gets the GeoJSON from the `url` every 2 seconds.
2. Gets the map's `'drone'` source using [`Map#getSource`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#getsource).
3. Sets the data used by the source in (2) to be the GeoJSON at the `url` using [`Map#setData`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geojsonsource#setdata).

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  map.getSource('drone').setData(url);
}, 2000);
```

Your current implementation is using HTML-based markers via GL JS's [`Marker`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker) component. So, instead of switching to this source-and-layer based approach outlined above, you could use the [`Marker#setLngLat`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker#setlnglat) method each time the user's location updates in your database. This also will not refresh the whole page.